# Remove the space between twitter

Tags: php, css, wordpress

[This is my blog](http://louismoore.net/wordpress/)... if you look on it and look at the side bar you can see my twitter feed. Currently if i tweet to someone then it dispays like this...
My username: 
Their user name 
Tweet

I would like it to be more like
My username: Their username
Tweet

Or

My username:
Their username - Tweet

Viewing the source code of the pages there actually no `<br>` displaying...

```
    <li>@LouisMoore18:  <span class='entry-content'>
<a href="http://twitter.com/FirstNorwich" class="twitter-user">@FirstNorwich</a> thank you! Is there any delays to the x1? If so how long?</span> 
<span class='entry-meta'><span class='time-meta'><a href="http://twitter.com/LouisMoore18/statuses/293686943156416512"></a></span> 
<span class="in-reply-to-meta">
<a href="http://twitter.com/FirstNorwich/statuses/293686435482071040" class="reply-to">in reply to FirstNorwich</a></span></span></li>
```

However its displaying as if their was one

This is the code that follows the person who i tweeted...

```
private function _linkTwitterUsersCallback( $matches ) {
    $linkAttrs = array(
        'href'  => 'http://twitter.com/' . urlencode( $matches[2] ),
        'class' => 'twitter-user'
    );
    return $matches[1] . $this->_buildLink( '@'.$matches[2], $linkAttrs );
}
```

This a wordpress plugin called Twitter Widget Pro

Comment: What's in the stylesheet?

Comment: `<h30>` huh? It only goes up to the number 6.

Comment: If you look at the source code of your website, there actually is a misformatted `<br>` tag written as `</br>`. Maybe you can find it with a search for the content in your files? It should be easily locatable, as it is written wrong. In the source code it’s between each list element (directly after the `</li>` you posted here).

Comment: @John i believe the style sheet isgrey.css

Comment: @John: It does not come from CSS. If you look at the page, you find these misformatted `<br>` tags and if you remove them from source (e.g. in Firebug), you see that it really goes closer.

Comment: @Aufziehvogel i had actually added that myself. Before i added it, it was still doing the same. Howver i have changed it to '<br>' now and still not doing what i want it to

Comment: @Louismoore18 Oh, sorry. I misread your question. You mean another position… It’s about the `h`-tags which are a so called ''block''-element. You have mainly two types of elements in web-development: ''block'' and ''inline''. ''Block'' means that it is rendered on it’s own line, ''inline'' means that other elements can be left and right of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your name is wrapped in a  heading tag.
By default this will behave as a "block" element, hence the line break effect.

Have a look at your stylesheet(s), add a rule for the h30 tags within the feed, setting them to display: inline should do the trick.

It also looks like your links (a tags) below need tweaking to be display: inline (or similar) too.

You could also look into the feed's code, changing the html elements it uses, but CSS is probably the easier and more maintainable approach.

Comment: added dispay:inline to the css and it changed nothing

Comment: To the ".widget ul li a:link" class too? That one's the key

Comment: You could probably get away with just removing the "display: block" from the ".widget ul li a:link" rule in style.css

Comment: Looks fine to me now you've changed it. Use Ctrl + F5 in your browser if it's not showing for you...

Answer (score 0):

Heading tags automatically add a line break when you close them.

Look at your source code.

```
<h30>
  @LouisMoore18: 
</h30><span class="entry-content">
  RT 
<a class="twitter-user" href="http://twitter.com/Jessewelle"></a>
  : This just happen! Nylah and Bamboo cuddling. 
<a href="http://t.co/pKJ3ZhD9"></a>
```

Re-arrange your tags, or update your stylesheet to show `<h30>` tag as inline.

Also, h30 really?